# updating sql table value

Tags: php, mysql

Attempting to update my members table in my database by subtracting 2 from the current value of the tokens value. Tried different variations and this is the closest I could get. I am not getting errors in my error log. But it's not changing the value of 'tokens' for the designated user in the table. What's missing? please help.

```
<?php
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/includes/db_connect.php';
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/includes/functions.php';
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

session_start();

$username=trim($_SESSION['username']);
$logged = 'logged in';

$tokenquery = 'UPDATE members SET tokens = tokens - 2 WHERE username = ?';

 if ($stmtlose = $mysqli->prepare($tokenquery)) {
   $stmtlose->bind_param('s',$username);
$stmtlose->execute();}
```

Comment: Error checking and problem description are missing.

Comment: updated. i'm not getting errors. yet it's not actually updating my table.

Comment: What's missing.... `session_start();` perhaps?

Comment: what is the value in $username?

Comment: `session_start();` is inside all your files, and how does `$logged` come into play? @KissingKings

Comment: $logged is irrelevant.

Comment: what is the value in $username, my guess is it's not what you think?

Comment: I suggest your start `var_dump()`'ing all of your variables.

Comment: Usually, you'll want to assign a session variable first, such as `$_SESSION['username']="KissingKings";` then use `$username=trim($_SESSION['username']);`

Comment: username is correct. adding `session_start();` i get `session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent`. adding `sec_session_start();`, it updates the table but i get the errors `session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent` and `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`. researching and learning what I'm mixing up. thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: could it be something as simple as wrapping tokens - 2 in parentheses? I know that shouldn't matter, but maybe...

Comment: There, you're outputting before headers, so either try adding `ob_start();` above `session_start();` or check for a cookie, a space before `<?php` or other (BOM) --- All nice and dandy, but `$username=trim($_SESSION['username']);` does nothing if there isn't an actual "user name" associated with it.

Comment: I'm sure if you do this `var_dump($_SESSION['username']);` (*using what you have now*) that your result will be **NULL** --- If you do `$_SESSION['username'] = "KissingKings"; $username=trim($_SESSION['username']); var_dump($username);` you will see `string(12) "KissingKings"` @KissingKings

Comment: added session start. got errors i posted a bit ago. I had a another.php being called before this .php that i posted in the question. I swapped the order of the two and now it all works as it should. I appreciate the help with troubleshooting and you guys learning me some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging is about creating and testing hypothesis.

Consider these "missing" things:

1. There is a missing check on the result of `execute`. The update query itself could be failing; e.g. failure could be caused by using an incorrect structure or violating constraints. (A succeeding `prepare` *does not guarantee* that the actual query execution will succeed!)
2. There is a missing check on the number of rows updated (via [`affected_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)). If no rows were affected then, trivially, WHERE didn't match any records - which would make $username suspect.
3. There is missing handling of what happens when `prepare` fails. The `bind/execute` (inside the if-statement) will not be run if `prepare` does not succeed.
4. In the unlikely case an explicit transaction is used, a commit may be missing.

I suspect that the issue will be revealed in the first two cases.